State healing taking over a month, faster way to sync etherium for transfer?
For context I last used geth and Etherium when it was PoW, then I left it for several years with a small amount of eth (~$80) in my wallet.
With the recent increase in price, I was reminded of this, so attempted to update geth enough to transfer my eth to an exchange to liquidate my position. I had previously used "light" mode, but that doesn't seem to be supported anymore. After a bunch of research, I backed up the wallet and wiped the .etherium folder to do a fresh sync, and it has downloaded 1.1TB of chain data, but it still refuses to finish syncing the "state healing". I left it on for 5 weeks so far, and it eventually got up to 16M accounts synced. Doing the math, syncing the current 264M accounts on the etherium chain will take well over a year. Given I would have to leave my computer on 24/7, and as I live in an expensive electricity region, it will cost me over $1000 in electricity just to sync geth enough to sell my ~$80 of eth.
Is there a faster way to sync up enough so that I can transfer the entire contents of my wallet to an exchange?
Current setup:
Debian 12, lighthouse 5.1.1 + geth 1.13.14. Machine is 24-core Threadripper 7960X, 256GB Ram, SSD (Sata+NVMe) storage. I had seen some comments about slow storage or low memory usage, or slow cpus, but I think my machine should be fast enough.
./lighthouse beacon --execution-endpoints=http://localhost:8551 --execution-jwt $HOME/.ethereum/geth/jwtsecret --http --checkpoint-sync-url https://mainnet.checkpoint.sigp.io
geth --syncmode=snap --exitwhensynced --cache 20000 console
INFO [04-17|19:52:26.058] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=719.83GiB  headers=19,678,587@9.02GiB   bodies=19,678,503@528.60GiB receipts=19,678,503@182.21GiB eta=13.129s
INFO [04-17|19:52:33.184] Syncing: state healing in progress       accounts=16,689,132@843.07MiB slots=22,257,816@1.65GiB      codes=13361@77.41MiB     nodes=163,056,074@46.52GiB pending=24557
INFO [04-17|19:52:34.062] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=100.00% chain=719.83GiB  headers=19,678,587@9.02GiB   bodies=19,678,503@528.60GiB receipts=19,678,503@182.21GiB eta=13.129s
INFO [04-17|19:52:37.213] Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=19,678,588 hash=2ed3ef..4a0f7a finalized=19,678,516


The spec looks ok but it does sound like the issue when my old raspberry pi became stuck, even with the t7 ssd. You should be able to sync and be up in a few hours from a checkpoint. Have you tried deleting the database and starting again maybe something is corrupt.

You don't need a synced node to transfer funds. :D
Just retrieve the private key from geth and use wallet like METAMASK or TRUST.
Use the option 'Import wallet by PRIVATE KEY'.
Hope you can get your eth, or just hodl ;D
